# gazebo supported graphics card

Tags: ros, gazebo, nvidia

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have checked "[simulator_gazebo/SystemRequirements](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/SystemRequirements)".

And I found the latest nvidia graphics card on that page is also very old.

I couldn't find the nVidia GTS 360M on the buyable list, and what I found is GTS 440,450,460,465,470,560,570,580.

Therefore I want to ask "Is there any update of that webpage?"

If possible I want to buy higher level of cards to run cuda on gazebo.

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9243/gazebo-supported-graphics-card/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for this information.
I found a ogre page :http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Hardware

It says "Always use the latest drivers provided by your graphics card vendor! (unless a certain driver version is known to give problems) ".

And I also check what version of nvidia card that ubuntu supported.

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/06/how-to-install-nvidia-25635-display.html

And the versions of nvidia package Linux x64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver of cards is

http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-270.18-driver.html

I list here a little bit:
GeForce 500 series:
GTX 570, GTX 580
GeForce 400 series:
GT 430, GTX 460, GTX 480, GTX 460 SE, GTX 470, GTX 465, GTS 45
...

Is that means I can choose GTX 580 to run gazebo on ubuntu 10.04 or 10.10?

Attached the full list of nvidia graphics card supported on ubuntu 10.04

```
 GeForce 500 series:
 GTX 570, GTX 580
 
 GeForce 400 series:
 GT 430, GTX 460, GTX 480, GTX 460 SE, GTX 470, GTX 465, GTS 450
 
 GeForce 400M series:
 GT 435M, GT 425M, GT 415M, GTX 480M, GTX 460M, GT 420M
 
 GeForce 300 series:
 GT 330, GT 340, 315, 310, GT 320
 
 GeForce 300M series:
 GT 320M, GTS 360M, GT 325M, GTS 350M, GT 330M, GT 335M, 305M, 310M
 
 GeForce 200 series:
 GT 230, GTX 285, GT 240, GTX 295, GTX 275, GTX 280, GTS 240, 205, GTX 260,      GT 220, G210, GTS 250
 
 GeForce 200M series:
 GTS 260M, G210M, GT 240M, GTX 280M, GT 220M, GTX 285M, GTX 260M, GT      230M, GTS 250M
 
 GeForce 100 series:
 GT 140, GT 120, G 100, GT 130
 
 GeForce 100M series:
 GTS 150M, G 102M, GT 130M, GTS 160M, G 103M, GT 120M, G 110M, G 105M
 
 GeForce 9 series:
 9300, 9300 GE, 9300 GS, 9800 GT, 9400, 9500 GS, 9600 GSO, 9300 SE, 9200,      9500 GT, 9800 GX2, 9800 GTX+, 9600 GS, 9100, 9300 / nForce 730i, 9600 GSO 512,      9400 GT, 9600 GT, 9800 GTX/GTX+, 9650 S
 
 GeForce 9M series:
 9200M GS, 9100M G, 9800M GS, 9400M G, 9500M GS, 9800M GTS, 9700M      GTS, 9700M GT, 9300M G, 9400M, 9800M GTX, 9600M GS, 9500M G, 9650M GS,      9650M GT, 9300M GS, 9800M GT, 9600M GT
 
 GeForce 8 series:
 8800 GT, 8100 / nForce 720a, 8400 SE, 8800 GS, 8300, 8800 GTX, 8200, 8800      GTS, 8500 GT, 8300 GS, 8600 GTS, 8400 GS, 8400, 8800 Ultra, 8800 GTS 512, 8600 GS
 
 GeForce 8M series:
 8700M GT, 8600M GT, 8600M GS, 8400M G, 8400M GS, 8800M GTX, 8200M G,      8400M GT, 8800M GTS
 
 GeForce 7 series:
 7000M /NVIDIA nForce 610M, 7025 / NVIDIA nForce 630a, 7300 SE / 7200 GS,      7300 GT, 7500 LE, 7650 GS, 7600 GS, 7150M /NVIDIA nForce 630M, 7300 LE, 7100 /      NVIDIA nForce 630i, 7950 GT, 7800 GS, 7050 PV / NVIDIA nForce 630a, 7150 / NVIDIA      nForce 630i, 7300 GS, 7600 LE, 7350 LE, 7800 GT, 7800 SLI, 7600 GT, 7050 / NVIDIA      nForce 630i, 7050 / nForce 620i, 7950 GX2, 7900 GT/GTO, 7900 GTX, 7900 GS, 7800      GTX, 7100 GS
 
 GeForce Go 7 series:
 Go 7900 GS, Go 7600 GT, Go 7400, Go 7300, Go 7950 GTX, Go 7200, Go 7800,      Go 7600, Go 7800 GTX, Go 7700
 
 GeForce 6 series:
 6600, 6150, 6800, 6100 nForce 405, 6800 LE, 6600 LE, 6200 A-LE, 6800 Ultra,      6200, 6800 GT, 6800 GS, 6250, 6800 XE, 6800 XT, 6600 VE, 6150SE nForce 430, 6100,      6200 LE, 6200SE TurboCache, 6700 XL, 6100 nForce 420, 6150 LE, 6500, 6610 XL,      6600 GT, 6200 TurboCache, 6100 nForce 400
 
 NVS Series:
 NVS 300
 
 Quadro series:
 6000, 2000, 600, 5000, 4000
 
 Quadro FX series:
 FX 1400, FX 1500, FX 580, FX 4500 X2, FX 5600, FX Go1400, FX 550, FX 4500, FX      3700, FX 4700 X2, FX 350, FX 540, FX 4000, FX 370 Low Profile, FX 3400/4400, FX 560,      FX 570, FX 4600, FX 4800, FX 3500, CX, FX 5500, FX 3800, FX 380 LP, FX 370, FX 5800,      FX 1800, FX 380, FX 3450/4000 SDI, FX 1700
 
 Quadro Notebook series:
 5000M
 
 Quadro FX Notebook series:
 FX 560M, FX 1600M, FX 2700M, FX 1500M, FX 370M, FX 2800M, FX 3600M, FX      540M, FX 2500M, FX 3800M, FX 1800M, FX 570M, FX 880M, FX 3700M, FX 360M, FX      350M, FX 770M, FX 1700M, FX 380M
 
 Quadro NVS series:
 NVS 450, NVS 210S / 6150LE, NVS 290, NVS 285, NVS 295, NVS 440, NVS 420
 
 Quadro NVS Notebook series:
 NVS 110M, NVS 120M, NVS 135M, NVS 150M, NVS 160M, NVS 130M, NVS      510M, NVS 140M, NVS 320M
 
 Quadro Plex series:
 Model II, D Series, Model IV, 7000
 
 Quadro G-Sync series:
 G-Sync II
 
 Quadro SDI series:
 Quadro SDI
 
 1U System:
 Tesla S2050, Tesla M2070-Q, Tesla M1060, Tesla M2070, Tesla M2050, T10      Processor
 
 ION series:
 ION, ION LE
 
 GPU Computing Processor series:
 Tesla C1060, Tesla C870, Tesla C2070, Tesla C2050
```

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2011-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-10-07**:
In this link may have some info:http://askubuntu.com/questions/61395/whats-the-latest-video-card-that-will-work-on-a-64-bit-system  . But I couldn't figure it out,you can have a try and post your result.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-05**:
@sam : What about 500M series ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general that page holds the aggregated results of individuals testing.  Hopefully as people try new cards they will write back there what works or doesn't work.  It's not complete and there's no systematic updating.  And unfortunately someone always has to take the risk and be the first to try the newer cards.  Though recently the likelyhood of getting a card which works has gone up.

If you want to look outside for more options I'd suggest that you look at what cards people report being able to run Ogre or other Ogre based applications.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried

1.Radeon HD 6570M

2.GTS 450

[image: image description]

3.GT520 ([driver version 295.33] (http://www.geforce.com/drivers/beta-legacy) with ubuntu 10.10)

4.GT520M ([driver version 295.33] (http://www.geforce.com/drivers/beta-legacy) with ubuntu 10.10)

5.GT550M with Optimus (using [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/index.html))

6.GT610M with Optimus (using [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/index.html))

7.GT630M with Optimus (using [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/index.html))

Those works very well!

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2011-12-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1